# Content Porter "Unable to save Publication (tcm:0-243-1)"

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

[image: Content Porter throwing error]  I am trying this with admin rights.Please help

```
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040200" Category="4" Source="Kernel" Severity="2" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040200" Cause="false" MessageID="16137">
        <![CDATA[Unable to save Publication (tcm:0-243-1).]]>tcm:Token>RESID_4574</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>RESID_4452</tcm:Token>tcm:Token>tcm:0-243-1</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040200" Cause="true" MessageID="15748"><![CDATA[Unable to map all paths to URIs.]]></tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Details>
        <tcm:CallStack>tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.UrlConversion.Convert()</tcm:Location>
        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs)</tcm:Location>
        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()</tcm:Location>
        <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.IdentifiableObjectFacade.Update(UserContext,String)</tcm:Location>
        <tcm:Location>XMLState.Save</tcm:Location>
        <tcm:Location>Publication.Save</tcm:Location>
        <tcm:Location>Request.SaveItem</tcm:Location>
        <tcm:Location>XMLResponder.Request</tcm:Location>
    </tcm:CallStack></tcm:Details>
</tcm:Error>
```

Comment: Make double click on error to see full error message, or take is from log. It's impossible to analyze without error message. Also probably package will be needed

Comment: I have updated the error code from log file .

Comment: Check the SDL Tridion eventlog on why the Publication cannot be saved, that might clarify things already

Comment: If you are doing the content porting first time on any of the environment, please verify if content porter hotfixes are applied or not.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are unable to save the Publication.

Can you check that all of the necessary parent Publications have been created?

Also, if your Publication Metadata contains links to other Components and/or Keywords, you will need to make sure that these are imported in advance or in the same import.

You may also want to check whether you can create this Publication manually.  The answers on the following Stack Overflow question (which also reports "Unable to map all paths to URIs") may also help:
[Content Porter SP1 throwing Error while importing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874630/content-porter-sp1-throwing-error-while-importing-content)